# Show login page when website is accessed from outside the intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-membership

I'm developing an intranet web application in ASP.NET MVC3 with some simple content management features. The website can be viewed by anyone within in the intranet, but edited only by registered users. From outside the intranet, the website should not be viewable by anyone but the registered users.

Is there a way to check whether someone is accessing the website from outside the intranet somehow and redirect them to the login page? Should this be done in IIS or C#? I really don't know which way to approach this problem. I would still like to use the highly convenient [Authorize] attributes.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using for your intranet users? Are you using Windows Authentication (NTLM)? And what about your extranet users? Do you intend to use Forms authentication for them?

Comment: I'm using forms authentication for intranet and extranet over SSL.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom Authorize attribute which will check if the client IP address belongs on the local intranet and allow anonymous access, otherwise require authentication:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var ip = httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (IsIntranetAddress(ip))
        {
            // The IP address of the client belongs on the intranet => 
            // allow anonymous access
            return true;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    private bool IsIntranetAddress(string ip)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now decorate your controllers/actions with the `[MyAuthorize]` attribute. Or if you want to apply it to all requests simply register it as a global action filter.

Comment: You don't think so that this should be handle at firewall/IIS level instead of application level.

Comment: How do you intend to redirect to the login page of your MVC application at the firewall level? The best you could do at the firewall is throw some 401 error status code but that's not what the OP wants. He wants to allow internet users to access the site if they get authenticated. A firewall doesn't operate on such a high level.

Comment: That looks excellent, thanks! I don't know how to register an attribute as a global action filter, though. Could you explain that?

Comment: In your Global.asax file there must be a method called `RegisterGlobalFilters` in which the `HandleErrorAttribute` is already registered as global filter. So all you have to do is to add your custom authorization filter to the `filters` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply restrict users from the firewall settings and also if you do not assign any Public ip than anyhow it's not going to access by internet users.

Comment: The point is not to restrict access completely (that's what I'm doing now), but require authorization for all extranet requests.

Comment: You can also do it by simply providing IP range of your private network. I dont have that much idea about this setting but you can do it in this way also.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me how to implement the different behaviour for intranet and extranet users.